# Deriving a uncertainty inequality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Starting from
$$(Δx) (Δp) \geq h/2$$
How does one derive
$$a^2 (Δx)^2 + (Δp)^2 \geq a h~? $$

Comment: Never mind I just figured it out.

Start with $$ [a (Δx) - (Δp)]^2 \geq 0 $$

Then just expand:

$$ a^2(Δx)^2 + (Δp)^2 - 2 a (Δx) (Δp) \geq 0 $$

$$ a^2(Δx)^2 + (Δp)^2 \geq 2 a (Δx) (Δp) \geq 2 a h/2 = ah $$

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question! Perhaps you should write one up!